# VSTO Addin for Excel not loading for non admin users

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I have developed a Excel addin and created an msi installer for it. In the setup project I put the registry entries to User/Machine hive. When I install for all users, it works well and when I open the Excel customization (*.xltx) it for non-admin user, I am getting 
`this addn is installed for all users on this computer and can only be connected or disconnected by an administrator`. 
How to solve this

Comment: I know this way (http://www.slipstick.com/problems/add-in-can-only-be-disabled-by-an-administrator/) can solve the problem. But I need this to work with Azure Remoteapp

Comment: Try installing your project for just the current user.  Do you still get the message?

Answer (score 0):

Non-admin users can't modify the HKLM hive. Take a look at the following links for more information:

[This add-in is installed for all users on this computer, and can only be connected or disconnected by an administrator](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-outlook/this-add-in-is-installed-for-all-users-on-this/7ec08ed2-d467-4441-96ed-990552949406?auth=1)

[Error: "This add-in is installed for all users on this computer, and can only be connected or disconnected by an administrator"](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/aed8a03d-81e7-4810-b33c-049ba24628ff/error-this-addin-is-installed-for-all-users-on-this-computer-and-can-only-be-connected-or?forum=exceldev)

[Add-in can only be Disabled by an Administrator](http://www.slipstick.com/problems/add-in-can-only-be-disabled-by-an-administrator/)